# how to inject and use mysql views instead tables on java spring POJO class. Is it possible to use views

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

How to inject @view instead table in POJO class on java spring.

> @Entity @Table(name="CANCELLED_REASONS")
>
> org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity:
>   com.xxx.med.model.CancelledReasons    at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:368)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1123)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1018)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.initMessageSource(AbstractApplicationContext.java:697)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:526)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:444)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:326)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.core.ApplicationListeners.contextInitialized(ApplicationListeners.java:187)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:198)
>     at
>   org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:100)
>     at
>   org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:82)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)    at
>   org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320) Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire field:
>   com.xxx.med.converter.RoleToUserProfileConverter
>   com.xxx.med.configuration.AppConfig.roleToUserProfileConverter;
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'roleToUserProfileConverter': Injection of
>   autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire field: com.xxx.med.service.UserProfileService
>   com.xxx.med.converter.RoleToUserProfileConverter.userProfileService;
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'userProfileService': Injection of autowired
>   dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire field: com.xxx.med.dao.UserProfileDao
>   com.xxx.med.service.UserProfileServiceImpl.dao; nested
>   exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'userProfileDao': Injection of autowired
>   dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory
>   com.xxx.med.dao.AbstractDao.sessionFactory; nested exception
>   is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path
>   resource
>   [com/xxx/med/configuration/HibernateConfiguration.class]:
>   Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity:
>   com.xxx.med.model.CancelledReasons    at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:573)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
>     ... 31 more Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'roleToUserProfileConverter': Injection of
>   autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire field: com.xxx.med.service.UserProfileService
>   com.xxx.med.converter.RoleToUserProfileConverter.userProfileService;
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'userProfileService': Injection of autowired
>   dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire field: com.xxx.med.dao.UserProfileDao
>   com.xxx.med.service.UserProfileServiceImpl.dao; nested
>   exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'userProfileDao': Injection of autowired
>   dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory
>   com.xxx.med.dao.AbstractDao.sessionFactory; nested exception
>   is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path
>   resource
>   [com/xxx/med/configuration/HibernateConfiguration.class]:
>   Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity:
>   com.xxx.med.model.CancelledReasons    at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1192)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1116)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:545)

Comment: Right way only...

Comment: no annotation available as @view. Is there any other way

Comment: View is  a logical table . So, using @Table annotation , you can achieve it

Comment: Hi sitakant facing this, if i use @Table. Error creating bean with name 'appConfig': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field. Dependency missing error

Comment: Error is different.... Could you post entire stack trace ?

Comment: Sitkant ive posted the stack trace :)

Comment: @Immutable
@Table(name="CANCELLED_REASONS").. If i provide table annotation its throwing error

Comment: It is definitely possible to use a View instead of a Table. You can test it by making a simple POJO mapping to one table. It looks like your error is from some other property referencing this entity or similar

Comment: Seems, your entity is not proper . Could you check this ?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25851029/org-hibernate-annotationexception-no-identifier-specified-for-entity-i-dont-hav

Else, Could you post your entity definition ?

Comment: Thanks Sitkant and Mmcrae for your support. It worked after a long war after removing @Immutable and added @Column(xxx , nullable = false)