# Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined : Java8

Tags: java, spring

in my D1 model:

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Id;
public class D1 
{
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id_client")
    private BigDecimal id_contrats;

    @Column(name = "name_client")
    private Timestamp dat_deb_dwh;

}
```

In D1Repository

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import java.util.Date;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import io.A1.B1.api.P1.data.model.D1;

@Entity(name = "tmp.c1")
@Table(name = "c1", schema="tmp") 
public interface D1Repository 
{
    @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM #{#entityName} )
    T getId(@Param("id_client") BigDecimal id_client);

}
```

I'm getting this error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity: io.A1.B1.api.P1.repository.D1Repository
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1778) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1105) ~[spring-context-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867) ~[spring-context-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142) ~[spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) [spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) [spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) [spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) [spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at io.A1.B1.api.App.main(App.java:13) [classes/:na]

Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity: io.A1.B1.api.P1.repository.D1Repository
    at org.hibernate.cfg.InheritanceState.determineDefaultAccessType(InheritanceState.java:266) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.InheritanceState.getElementsToProcess(InheritanceState.java:211) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:775) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.source.internal.annotations.AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.processEntityHierarchies(AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.java:250) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess$1.processEntityHierarchies(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:231) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:274) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:904) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:935) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:57) ~[spring-orm-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390) ~[spring-orm-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:377) ~[spring-orm-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1837) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1774) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
```

Please if you can help please don't hesitate.

Thank you

Comment: Take a look at the stacktrace, it says "nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity: io.A1.B1.api.P1.repository.D1Repository"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Org.Hibernate.AnnotationException: No Identifier Specified For Entity I don't have a id in my table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25851029/org-hibernate-annotationexception-no-identifier-specified-for-entity-i-dont-ha)

Comment: @f1sh Thank you for your response, i edited my original post to be more specific, please have a look :)

Comment: Your `D1Repository` is not an entity, so it shouldn't be annotated as such, and `D1` is, so it should be annotated.

Comment: [1] To those voting to close this as a duplicate, the linked duplicate has ten answers none of which were accepted. Given that, how does closing this question as a duplicate actually help the OP here with their problem? [2] More generally, just because a question mentions the same error as an existing question, that does not automatically make it a duplicate. [3] If you vote to close this question as a duplicate please also specify which answer is relevant in the linked duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add @Entity to specify this is an entity and @Table(name = "insert_table_name") to specify it's relation with the database table on top of your class.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "c1", schema="tmp") 
public class D1 
{
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id_client")
    private BigDecimal id;

    @Column(name = "name_client")
    private Timestamp dat_deb_dwh;

}

public interface D1Repository extends CrudRepository<D1, BigDecimal>
{

    D1 findById(BigDecimal id_client);

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Entity and table are added also and the error persists. I have edited my original post , please have a look

Comment: You need to add the annotations to your entity (D1), not the repository.

Comment: I added this rows before D1 model and still have the error **import javax.persistence.Entity;
    import javax.persistence.Table;
    @Entity(name = "tmp.c1")
    @Table(name = "c1", schema="tmp")**

Comment: yes i did it also @ntholi and i have added import javax.persistence.Entity; import javax.persistence.Table; @Entity(name = "tmp.c1") @Table(name = "c1", schema="tmp") before my D1 model class but still got the same error

Comment: I have updated my original answer with some corrections, removed name parameter from entity annotation, extended CrudRepository in your reposityory and changed the query to reflect Spring Data JPA standards.